# REGEX to match the last nested token

Tags: java, regex

I need to create a REGEX that will capture the last
expression of the 'if' clause.

For example, given the following statement:

```
  if ( if( (1+1 == 2, 1, 2)), 3);
```

I want to match:

```
((1+1 == 2, 1, 2))
```

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
if\(\.*^(?!if)\)
```

Comment: also there can be nested parenthesis inside the last if, 
e.g. if ( if( ( x + y) *2 > 2, 1, 2)), 3);

Comment: and so i want to retrieve only  (( x + y) *2 > 2, 1, 2)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following regex:

```
if\(\s*\([^()]*\)\)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jG2qJU/1)

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("if\\(\\s*\\([^()]*\\)\\)").matcher("if ( if( (1+1 == 2, 1, 2)), 3);");
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
if( (1+1 == 2, 1, 2))
```

**Explanation of the regex from [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jG2qJU/1):**

[image]

Comment: please check my comment to the question, this regex also don't work with nested parentheses

Comment: but thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

This regexp runs , the result is in in group 1 ( $1 )

> ^if\s?((.*),.*);$

Comment: i tried to run it on https://regex101.com/ but a test also failed